# running a process in c#

Tags: c#, process.start

i want to run a process programaticaly in c#.
with process.start i can do it. but how can i prommt user when the process asks for some user input in between and continue again after providing the input.

Comment: How exactly is the process asking for input?

Comment: lets take an example of c compiler. if i m compiling c code programaticaly through c#, wherever there is scanf statement in c code, my appliocation should alert user for inpurt. and process should continue after providing input. how can i get the actual status of running process 

in simple words i want provide a custom UI to the running process throug c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write to [Process.StandardInput](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput).

Comment: Note that you need to set ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute to false, and you must set ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput to true. Otherwise, writing to the StandardInput stream throws an exception.

Comment: @John Buchanan: Thanks for repeating exactly (actually copying) what it says on the link I provided...

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event handler to the OutputDataReceived event.
This gets called whenever the process writes some data to its redirected output stream.

```
private StreamWriter m_Writer;

public void RunProcess(string filename, string arguments)
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = filename;
    psi.Arguments = arguments;
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;

    Process process = Process.Start(psi);
    m_Writer = process.StandardInput;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnOutputDataReceived);
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
}

protected void OnOutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // Data Received From Application Here
    // The data is in e.Data
    // You can prompt the user and write any response to m_Writer to send
    // The text back to the appication
}
```

In addition there is also a Process.Exited event to detect if your process Exits.